# Sublime Text 3 Phpcs not working on Windows7

Tags: php, sublimetext3, phpcodesniffer

I have installed PHPCS using @install package in my Sublime Text3 . I can see Tools->PHP Code Sniffer:Sniff this file command, but when i select 'Sniff this file' command nothing happens.
Here is my Prefrences->Package Settings->PHP Code Sniffer->Settings default

```
{
// Plugin settings

// Turn the debug output on/off
"show_debug": false,

// Which file types (file extensions), do you want the plugin to
// execute for
"extensions_to_execute": ["php"],

// Do we need to blacklist any sub extensions from extensions_to_execute
// An example would be ["twig.php"]
"extensions_to_blacklist": [],

// Execute the sniffer on file save
"phpcs_execute_on_save": true,

// Show the error list after save.
"phpcs_show_errors_on_save": true,  

// Show the errors in the gutter
"phpcs_show_gutter_marks": true,

// Show outline for errors
"phpcs_outline_for_errors": true,

// Show the errors in the status bar
"phpcs_show_errors_in_status": true,

// Show the errors in the quick panel so you can then goto line
"phpcs_show_quick_panel": true,

// The path to the php executable.
// Needed for windows, or anyone who doesn't/can't make phars
// executable. Avoid setting this if at all possible
"phpcs_php_prefix_path": "G:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",

// Options include:
// - Sniffer
// - Fixer
// - Mess Detector
//
// This will prepend the application with the path to php
// Needed for windows, or anyone who doesn't/can't make phars
// executable. Avoid setting this if at all possible
"phpcs_commands_to_php_prefix": ["Fixer"],


// PHP_CodeSniffer settings

// Do you want to run the phpcs checker?
"phpcs_sniffer_run": true,

// Execute the sniffer on file save
"phpcs_command_on_save": true,

// It seems python/sublime cannot always find the phpcs application
// If empty, then use PATH version of phpcs, else use the set value
"phpcs_executable_path":  "G:\\xampp\\php\\phpcs.bat",

// Additional arguments you can specify into the application
//
// Example:
// {
//     "--standard": "PEAR",
//     "-n"
// }
"phpcs_additional_args": {
    "--standard": "PEAR",
    "-n": ""
},



// PHP-CS-Fixer settings

// Fix the issues on save
"php_cs_fixer_on_save": false,

// Show the quick panel
"php_cs_fixer_show_quick_panel": false,

// Path to where you have the php-cs-fixer installed
"php_cs_fixer_executable_path":  "G:\\xampp\\php\\php-cs-fixer.phar",

// Additional arguments you can specify into the application
//
// Example:
// {
//     "--level": "all"
// }
"php_cs_fixer_additional_args": {
    "--level": "all"
},



// PHP Linter settings

// Are we going to run php -l over the file?
"phpcs_linter_run": true,

// Execute the linter on file save
"phpcs_linter_command_on_save": true,

// It seems python/sublime cannot always find the php application
// If empty, then use PATH version of php, else use the set value
"phpcs_php_path": "G:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",

// What is the regex for the linter? Has to provide a named match for 'message' and 'line'
"phpcs_linter_regex": "(?P<message>.*) on line (?P<line>\\d+)",



// PHP Mess Detector settings

// Execute phpmd
"phpmd_run": false,

// Execute the phpmd on file save
"phpmd_command_on_save": true,

// It seems python/sublime cannot always find the phpmd application
// If empty, then use PATH version of phpmd, else use the set value
"phpmd_executable_path": "",

// Additional arguments you can specify into the application
//
// Example:
// {
//     "codesize,unusedcode"
// }
"phpmd_additional_args": {
    "codesize,unusedcode,naming": ""
},


// PHP Scheck settings

// Execute scheck
"scheck_run": false,

// Execute the scheck on file save
"scheck_command_on_save": false,

// It seems python/sublime cannot always find the scheck application
// If empty, then use PATH version of scheck, else use the set value
"scheck_executable_path": "",

// Additional arguments you can specify into the application
//
//Example:
//{
//  "-php_stdlib" : "/path/to/pfff",
//  "-strict" : ""
//}
"scheck_additional_args": {
    "-strict" : ""
}
```

}

Moreover, I can see PHPCS details using `phpcs -i` command and can sniff my code files using CLI, but nothing shows up in sublime :(

Comment: You may try SublimeLinter and SublimeLinter-phpcs and see if that works

Comment: Do you have any error messages in the console?

Comment: did you get any workaround for this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Setting up on a Windows 7, Wamp Server environment, I fixed this by making sure

```
"phpcs_commands_to_php_prefix": ["Fixer"]
```

was

```
"phpcs_commands_to_php_prefix": []
```

i.e "Avoid setting this if at all possible"

Also:

```
"phpcs_php_prefix_path": "G:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe"
```

can be

```
"phpcs_php_prefix_path": "G:\\xampp\\php\\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case did you forget to start your file with

```
<?php
```

instead of only

```
<?
```

If you skipped this then phpcs will not able to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the path phpcs_php_prefix_path value to "G:\xampp\php\", removing php.exe.